# Java error when using git-credential-manager in Mac on OSX?

Tags: git, macos

I have installed and configured git-credential-manager on Mac OSX according to these instructions:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/blob/master/Install.md

The brew install complained about a missing Java requirement and suggested a command to install Java, which I did.

After completing everything, I now get the following error when trying to perform a git clone from a private repository:

```
Cloning into 'Weather'...
Fatal: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException encountered.  Details:
Unrecognized version string '9+181'.
fatal: credential helper '!/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-
9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true 
-jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.3/libexec/git-credential-
manager-2.0.3.jar' told us to quit
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oct. 2017: That is tracked with [Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux issues/69](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/issues/69)

> I dumped Java 9 and installed Java 8, and everything worked just fine.

```
brew cask remove java
```

Reinstall git-credential-manager

```
git-credential-manager install
```

> I stumbled on the same issue as @JoeyHerrington and installed JDK8 instead:

```
brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8
```

**Update Sept. 2018**: the [same issue now includes](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/issues/69#issuecomment-421056187):

> version 2.0.4 of Git Credential Manager now supports Java 9+.
>   The update is available on GitHub and will be available on Homebrew soon.

So the OP (one year later) should not be an problem anymore.

---

[Thomas Hagström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708297/thomas-hagstr%C3%B6m) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770453/java-error-when-using-git-credential-manager-in-mac-on-osx/46782697?noredirect=1#comment86554112_46782697):

> I would say removing the folders is safest.
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" 
> sudo rm -rf "/Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane" 
> sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Application Support/Oracle" 
> sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Java"
> ```
>
> Then reinstall git credential manager so it picks up the correct Java version / virtual machine.

Comment: I uninstalled Java 9 and installed Java , but when I run git clone, I now get: Olavs-MacBook-Pro:Repos olavt$ git clone https://olavt.visualstudio.com/_git/Weather
Cloning into 'Weather'...
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.3/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.3.jar get: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: @OlavT Could you try and uninstall/reinstall the credential manager?

Comment: I tried it on another Mac and it works fine if you install Java 8.

Comment: @OlavT So something went wrong when installing the credential manager with JDK9...

Comment: I would say removing the folders is safest. Then reinstall git credential manager so it picks up the correct Java version / virtual machine
```sudo rm -rf "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin"```

```sudo rm -rf "/Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane"```

```sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Application Support/Oracle"```

```sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Java"```

Comment: @ThomasHagström Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: When in doubt of the configuration, review file `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: I did only the `git-credential-manager install` and it works as usual. It broke after brew upgrade on macos

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after I inserted some wrong credentials requested by `git` while using `IntelliJ`. I solved it by changing the `helper` in `~/.gitconfig`, (like @Migg said :). My `gitconfig` was pointed to the `Java 8`, and how I had already installed `Java 8` `and Java 11` installed in my machine (`OSX 10.14`). I just pointed to the newest version.

#### Before

```
[user]
    email = <email>
    name = <name>
[core]
    autocrlf = input
[credential]
    helper = !/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<java-1.8>/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar
```

#### After

```
credential]
        helper = !/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. One small addition: the path mentioned does not seem to be completely correct, I changed it to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (so without the jre) and then it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Fixed it by removing the credential setting altogether.